# Unable to find CDI BeanManager

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, wildfly

I'm trying to set up a simple application to use SpringBoot 2.1.1 and Java 11 over Wildfly 14 (because Wildfly 15 isn't supported by Eclipse).

The deploy failed because Wildfly cannot find the CDI BeanManager in the project. I'm only trying to follow the simple (official) tutorial, so I don't understand why the error appears.

This is the code:

pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <start-class>main</start-class>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<!-- Add typical dependencies for a web application -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<!-- Package as an executable jar -->
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Application.java

```
package main;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

This is the stacktrace:

```
> 12:51:13,365 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "SpringBoot-0.0.1.war" (runtime-name: "SpringBoot-0.0.1.war")
> WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
> WARNING: Illegal reflective access by io.undertow.util.FlexBase64$1 (jar:file:/C:/Users/87003556/Documents/Java/Wildfly%2014/modules/system/layers/base/io/undertow/core/main/undertow-core-2.0.13.Final.jar!/) to constructor java.lang.String(char[],boolean)
> WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of io.undertow.util.FlexBase64$1
> WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
> WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
> 12:51:13,429 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 127.0.0.1:8443
> 12:51:13,531 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.2.3.Final (Apache CXF 3.2.5.jbossorg-1) 
> 12:51:15,606 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpResponse$ResponseAsyncListener due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
> 12:51:15,606 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletHttpHandlerAdapter$HandlerResultAsyncListener due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
> 12:51:15,622 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
> 12:51:15,622 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
> 12:51:15,622 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpRequest$RequestAsyncListener due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
> 12:51:15,794 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-7) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Estrella Galicia' 9.3.1.Final
> 12:51:15,966 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from ejb container
> 12:51:16,075 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85) 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
> 12:51:16,153 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85) Initializing Mojarra 2.3.5.SP2 for context '/SpringBoot-0.0.1'
> 12:51:16,761 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85) Critical error during deployment: : com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory 'javax.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactory' was not configured properly.
>   at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:357)
>   at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:243)
>   at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:443)
>   at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:237)
>   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
>   at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:216)
>   at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:185)
>   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
>   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
>   ...
>   at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
> Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: Unable to find CDI BeanManager
>   at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.isJsf23(ApplicationImpl.java:2714)
>   at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.addELResolver(ApplicationImpl.java:549)
>   ...
>   at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:292)
>   at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:354)
>   ... 29 more
> 
> 12:51:16,761 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."SpringBoot-0.0.1.war".undertow-deployment: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."SpringBoot-0.0.1.war".undertow-deployment: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory 'javax.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactory' was not configured properly.
>   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
>   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
>   ...
>   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:825)
>   at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory 'javax.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactory' was not configured properly.
>   at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:252)
>   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:96)
>   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
>   ... 8 more
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory 'javax.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactory' was not configured properly.
>   at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:315)
>   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
>   at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:216)
>   at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:185)
>   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
>   ...
>   at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:250)
>   ... 10 more
> Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory 'javax.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactory' was not configured properly.
>   at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:357)
>   ...
>   at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:237)
>   ... 26 more
> Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: Unable to find CDI BeanManager
>   at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.isJsf23(ApplicationImpl.java:2714)
>   at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.addELResolver(ApplicationImpl.java:549)
>   at org.jboss.as.jsf.injection.weld.WeldApplication.<init>(WeldApplication.java:60)
>   at org.jboss.as.jsf.injection.weld.WeldApplicationFactory.getApplication(WeldApplicationFactory.java:52)
>   at com.sun.faces.application.InjectionApplicationFactory.getApplication(InjectionApplicationFactory.java:88)
>   ... at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:292)
>   at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:354)
>   ... 29 more
> 
> 12:51:16,762 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "SpringBoot-0.0.1.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"SpringBoot-0.0.1.war\".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory 'javax.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactory' was not configured properly.
>     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory 'javax.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactory' was not configured properly.
>     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory 'javax.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactory' was not configured properly.
>     Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory 'javax.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactory' was not configured properly.
>     Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: Unable to find CDI BeanManager"}}
> 12:51:16,762 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 42) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "SpringBoot-0.0.1.war" (runtime-name : "SpringBoot-0.0.1.war")
> 12:51:16,762 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
> WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."SpringBoot-0.0.1.war".undertow-deployment: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory 'javax.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactory' was not configured properly.
```

Comment: Did you consider adding the cdi-api to your pom.xml dependencies? It's not included within the dependencies you specified. <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
   <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: It works, thanks.
What I don't understand is why Spring doesn't include CDI in their parent POM (or, at least, specify that this dependency it's needed) :/

Comment: Cool! I'm glad it worked. If you don't mind, I'll post the same information below as an answer? It will be easier to read with the formatting. If this solves the issue, would you mind accepting the answer by clicking on the grey checkmark next to it, making it green?

Comment: @Assafs No need to prompt users to give you rep.  The system works.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments, the solution might be as simple as adding the `cdi-api` to your **pom.xml** dependencies. It's not included within the dependencies you specified.

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId> 
    <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId> 
    <version>1.2</version> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: further if error comes kindly add below dependency 
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.reactivestreams</groupId>
   <artifactId>reactive-streams</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 2):

Remember, is necessary to include the context that start the CDI configuration.

> 

```
<Resource name="BeanManager" auth="Container" type="javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager" factory="org.apache.webbeans.container.ManagerObjectFactory" />
```

[You can check the all setup here](https://balusc.omnifaces.org/2013/10/how-to-install-cdi-in-tomcat.html)

Or you can review this [blog](http://fritzthecat-blog.blogspot.com/2019/08/jsf-23-maven-project-in-eclipse.html)

Comment: This fixed it for me, since my project is not maven.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly related to your Problem, but maybe it might help someone else.

We are using SpringBoot with [joinfaces](http://joinfaces.org/), in our case the problem was caused by an error in the `faces-config.xml` - specifically in the header part `<faces-config ...>`. Maybe check your `git`, if the file was updated recently.